# Using multiple CA certificates for Apache SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, https, certificate, ca

I have two virtual hosts, and use two certificates.  While not indicated by the following httpd.conf file, I am using *.example.com as well as *.sites.example.com and thus need to the two certificates.  When accessing https://bla.sites.example.com/, the browser displays the following warning:

```
bla.sites.example.com uses an invalid security certificate.
The certificate is only valid for the following names: *.example.com, example.com
(Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)
```

If I remove the first VirtualHost which redirects to www.example.com, I don't get the warning.

Why is this, and how should I use multiple CA certificates for different VirtualHosts?

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite SSLv3:TLSv1:+HIGH:!SSLv2:!MD5:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!EXP:!ADH:!eNULL:!aNULL
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/example_key.pem
    #Following certificate is good for example.com and *.example.com
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/example_startssl_class2.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/sub.class2.server.ca.pem
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.sites.example.com
    ErrorDocument 404 /error-404.html
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/html_sites
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite SSLv3:TLSv1:+HIGH:!SSLv2:!MD5:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!EXP:!ADH:!eNULL:!aNULL
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/example_key.pem
    #Following certificate is good for example.com, sites.example.com and *.sites.example.com
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/example_startssl_sites_class2.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/sub.class2.server.ca.pem
    <Directory "/var/www/example/html_sites">
        allow from all
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that I have the following settings in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:

```
#Following certificate is good for example.com and *.example.com
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/example_startssl_class2.crt
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/example_startssl_class2.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/example_key.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/sub.class2.server.ca.pem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your VHOST's are not setup correctly. You have both pointing to `ServerName example.com`

They both should have different specific `ServerName` and different document roots. Then apache will know where to send the request to the correct vhost and you won't get that error.

**You can see more configuration help here. [Multiple Certs using SNI](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-multiple-ssl-certificates-using-sni.htm)**

Since they are two different certs, your vhosts should look something like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/html_sites
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite SSLv3:TLSv1:+HIGH:!SSLv2:!MD5:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!EXP:!ADH:!eNULL:!aNULL
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/example_key.pem
    #Following certificate is good for example.com and *.example.com
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/example_startssl_class2.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/sub.class2.server.ca.pem
    <Directory "/var/www/example/html_sites">
        ErrorDocument 404 /error-404.html
        allow from all
        Options +Indexes
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R,L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName bla.sites.example.com
    ServerAlias *.sites.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example2/html_sites
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite SSLv3:TLSv1:+HIGH:!SSLv2:!MD5:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!EXP:!ADH:!eNULL:!aNULL
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/example_key.pem
    #Following certificate is good for example.com, sites.example.com and *.sites.example.com
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/example_startssl_sites_class2.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/sub.class2.server.ca.pem
    <Directory "/var/www/example2/html_sites">
        allow from all
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also to remember to restart apache when making changes.

Comment: Thanks Panama,  I believe you are correct in that I should have used different server names.  Guess I incorrectly thought that the first one would never be hit if the url was bla.sites.example.com.